# Mapping issue in hashicorp vault for users from keycloak

Tags: keycloak, hashicorp-vault

I need you advice, I've configured an integration Keycloak Quarkus and Hashicorp Vault and looks fine except issue with mapping.
When user log in in to Vault via OIDC keycloak provider it looks like:

Name: da5963da-e058-467c-ad52-c6e486ae98e0
ID: 3e7e89ec-8cea-934e-5dd2-8aa7170e5bf4
Entity ID: d0e03a06-70bb-db52-029c-7019b374e894
Mount: auth/oidc/oidc auth_oidc_8ee62108
Created: Oct 06, 2022 8:54 PM
Last Updated: Oct 06, 2022 8:54 PM

Token ID has all info, name, login, etc.
Very appreciated for any advice how to map correctly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not well asked, but it looks like you're providing the output from an `identity/entity-alias/id/${id}` call. It seems like the role you're using to log in on the `auth/oidc/oidc` mount point is using a `user_claim` value that is some sort of object id. Generally, with OIDC providers, there are all sorts of *claims* that can be sent across in the OIDC token, and you've defaulted to using a GUID that represents the user. Often, there are other claims available, like `email`, that can be leveraged to provide an alias name that is more user friendly.

So, if you hit `auth/oidc/oidc/config` and provide a `default_role` parameter, everyone that logs in will use that role. If you are getting people to use specific roles depending on some use case, then you will have to hit each configured role at `auth/oidc/oidc/role/${role}` and change the `user_claim` to something that Keycloak provides in its standard OIDC response claims.

Looking into the Keycloak documentation, it seems like there are very few standard claims, and you will have to configure what fields to include in your OIDC responses. [This blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/11/24/authentication-and-authorization-using-the-keycloak-rest-api) seemed like a decent enough primer on how to attach fields to your OIDC responses from Keycloak. The key part is the JSON representation of the response. From the linked blog post:

```json
{
    "sub": "ef2cbe43-9748-40e5-aed9-fe981e3082d5",
    "roles": [
        "teacher"
    ],
    "name": "Edwin M",
    "preferred_username": "edwin",
    "given_name": "Edwin",
    "family_name": "M"
}
```

Any of the fields above can be leveraged in your OIDC role configuration as `bound_claims`, `claim_mappings`, `user_claim`, etc. But none of these fields seem like a good fit for a unique user identifier. You will probably have to go further in the blog post to add things like username/email and change your `user_claim` field to one of those. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes it is my bad and wrong description. I already configured SSO between Keycloak and Vault and issue is I can't see name, given_name, or even email in Hashicorp Vault GUI. I see only entity_42h34 and sub: "ef2cbe43-9748-40e5-aed9-fe981e3082d5". It is not a big problem I could find user in Keycloak by his sub id but I would like to get "UserName" from KC instead "entity_23423". This was my question...